# how to add Datatable in table that have Div inside td

Tags: html, datatable

I have below table with tr td, td contain div inside it how can i add Datatable with seraching and pagination so in this below table i want to add pagination and search using Datatable.

```
   <table width=100% id="example1" class="display">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="card faq-item">
            <div id="faq-tab-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faq-tab-1-header" data- 
                  parent="#faq-tab-accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>
                  description
                </p>
                <a style="color: #fff;" target="_blank" href="complain_details.php?cid=1" class="btn 
                      btn-md btn-primary">Read More
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="card faq-item">
            <div id="faq-tab-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faq-tab-1-header" data- 
                 parent="#faq-tab-accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>
                  description
                </p>
                <a style="color: #fff;" target="_blank" href="complain_details.php?cid=1" class="btn 
                   btn-md btn-primary">Read More
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
</table>
```

### javascript

```
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example1').DataTable();
     } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a few required elements for the plugin to work. As per the documentation for [DataTables Installation](https://datatables.net/manual/installation):

> For DataTables to be able to enhance an HTML table, the table must be valid, well formatted HTML, with a header (`thead`) and a single body (`tbody`). An optional footer (`tfoot`) can also be used.

Per the documentation, a working snippet of HTML would look like:

```html
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now to update your code with the above structure I have included a `thead` with a column header cell and modified the existing cell text values so you can see the search functioning.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example1').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table width=100% id="example1" class="display">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Table Header Cell
      </td>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="card faq-item">
          <div id="faq-tab-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faq-tab-1-header" data- parent="#faq-tab-accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p>
                description one
              </p>
              <a style="color: #fff;" target="_blank" href="complain_details.php?cid=1" class="btn 
                      btn-md btn-primary">Read More
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="card faq-item">
          <div id="faq-tab-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faq-tab-1-header" data- parent="#faq-tab-accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p>
                description two
              </p>
              <a style="color: #fff;" target="_blank" href="complain_details.php?cid=1" class="btn 
                   btn-md btn-primary">Read More
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```